# Add random values to json data in Python

Tags: python, json

I am new to python.I want read a json file and add random values to it.The json contains subset too.I am unable to solve this.

```
sample.json

{"name": "Kash","age": 12,"loc": {"loc1":"Uk","loc2":"Usa"}}






import json
import random
f=open("sample.json")
data=json.load(f)


def iterate(dictionary):
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        dictionary[key]=random.randrange(1,10)
        print(dictionary)
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            iterate(value)
    return dictionary

iterate(data)





Output I Got

{'name': 8, 'age': 12, 'loc': {'loc1': 'tc', 'loc2': 'cbe'}}
{'name': 8, 'age': 6, 'loc': {'loc1': 'tc', 'loc2': 'cbe'}}
{'name': 8, 'age': 6, 'loc': 9}
{'loc1': 5, 'loc2': 'cbe'}
{'loc1': 5, 'loc2': 1}
```

===========================================

Output Expected

```
{"name": 15,"age": 85,"loc": {"loc1":52,"loc2":36}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dictionary[key] = random.randrange(1,10)
```

This is performing:

```
dictionary['loc'] = some_number
```

So you lose the nested dict that was already there.

You only want to modify keys that do not have a dict as a value.

```
def iterate(dictionary):
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            iterate(value)
        else:
            dictionary[key] = random.randrange(1, 10)
    return dictionary
```

If your JSON can contain lists - you will need to handle that case too.

Comment: thank you but my code will add random numbers to the dict set as well as its subset,whereas I want to store/put them back into json fomat..